# How can I solve this differential equation with upto 12th grade math?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$f''(x)+ \frac{2}{x}\cdot f'(x)$ = $c\cdot f(x)$

Where c is a constant.

I tried multiplying by $e^{\int \frac{2}{x}} = x^2$

So I get,

$x^2 \cdot f''(x) +2x \cdot f'(x) = c\cdot x^2\cdot f(x)$

Thus $\frac{d}{dx}({x^2\cdot f'(x)}) = c\cdot x^2 \cdot f(x)$

How do I proceed from here ?

Comment: Multiply this thing on RHS as well!

Comment: Sorry... did that now..

Comment: Yes another editing mistake by me... sorry

Comment: Hint: Differentiate $x f(x)$ twice.